# Client Address is not showing correct in Event Log

Tags: windows-server-2008, login, windows-event-log, eventviewer, security

I had enable the Advance Audit Policy Configuration on my Domain Controller.

Server OS - Window Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Client OS - Window XP

Whenever the Domain User enter wrong password for their account i received the following Failure Audit. In this log, the Client address shown is

Client Address:        ::ffff:10.1.1.12 ( Please see the Print-screen attached )
[image]

But in Actual, the Client Address is different. Why it does not show the actual Client Address? Please let me know what does Client Address means here.

As per my understanding, it must be the address of the Client Workstation from where the Domain user had tried to login, but had failed because of, entering wrong password for their username.

Please explain?